# How to consume Page<Entity> response using Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-webflux

I have a REST Service which is returning a Page, while consuming it from WebClient its throwing the following exception.

I have also tried with CustomPageImpl but sill this issue persists.

```
Mono<CustomPageImpl<AssetDTO>> assetDTOMono = getWebClient()
.get()
.uri(getAeMaintenanceClientConfig().getAssetsByOrderNumberURI(), 
orderBuid, orderNumber)
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.headers(httpHeaders ->                 httpHeaders.set(SecurityTokenService.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, securityTokenService.getTokenValue(badgeId)))
.retrieve()
.onStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND::equals, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new Exception(messageResolver.message(MessageKey.NOT_FOUND, orderBuid, orderNumber))))
.onStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED::equals, clientResponse -> Mono.error(new Exception(messageResolver.message(MessageKey.USER_UNAUTHORIZED))))
.bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<CustomPageImpl<AssetDTO>>() {}).;

return assetDTOMono.block();
```

"org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information"

Here is the REST service which I want to call.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Find Assets by OrderNumber and OrderBuid")
@GetMapping(value = "/assets", params = {"ordernumber", "orderbuid"})
public ResponseEntity<Page<AssetDTO>> findAssetsByOrderNumberAndBuidAndConditions(@RequestParam(value = "ordernumber") String orderNumber, @RequestParam(value = "orderbuid") Long orderBuid,
                                                                                  @RequestParam(value = "creationdate", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime creationDate, @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) @RequestParam(value = "shipdate", required = false) ZonedDateTime shipDate,
                                                                                  @RequestParam(value = "installdate", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime installDate, @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) @RequestParam(value = "deinstalldate", required = false) ZonedDateTime deInstallDate,
                                                                                  @ModelAttribute("bySOrder") AssetAdvancedSearchFilter bySOrder,
                                                                                  @SortDefault.SortDefaults(value = {
                                                                                          @SortDefault(value = "customerProductId", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC),
                                                                                          @SortDefault(value = "orderNum", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC),
                                                                                          @SortDefault(value = "orderTieNum", direction = Sort.Direction.ASC),
                                                                                          @SortDefault(value = "shippedDateTz", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC)}) Pageable pageable) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(assetAdvancedService.findAssetsByAdvancedConditions(null, orderNumber, orderBuid, creationDate, shipDate, installDate, deInstallDate, bySOrder, pageable));
}
```

Comment: what i s `CustomPageImpl<AssetDTO>` please post these two classes

Comment: That was the custom PageImpl class which I have created extending like `public class CustomPageImpl<T> extends PageImpl<T>` . I have tried this as it was failing to create the instance of Pageable as shown in the exception above.

Comment: please dont explain what it is, post the code its impossible to help someone if not all the code is there.